# Are non-Cocoa command-line applications compatible with the Mac App Store?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, safari, mac-app-store

I would like to place a Safari extension on the Mac App Store, but this isn't possible directly.  Therefore, I want to create a wrapper application that simply installs / uninstalls the Safari extension, and place this application on the Mac App Store.

Are command-line applications like this accepted into the Mac App Store?  If so, must they be Cocoa-based?

Answer (score 2):

Only Apple knows. It's better for you to ask thé question at Apple's own developer forums. You know there is such a thing, right?

So, go to [the Apple developer forum](http://devforums.apple.com/).

There's a document called [Submitting to thé Mac App Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572), too.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, by now the answer is very clear:

1) installing a browser extension is not allowed for the Mac App Store apps

2) there are no command-line apps on MAS, so I'm pretty sure those are not allowed either

Just didn't want for the question to stay unanswered. :-)